# How do I connect my alexa app to dynamo db with the alexa node sdk?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have created a lambda function that attempts to make a connection with Dynamo DB through the [Alexa Skills Kit for Node](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=not%20authorized) according to the documentation all you need to connect to the database is

```
alexa.dynamoDBTableName = 'YourTableName'; // That's it!
```

For some reason I get the following error

```
User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/lambda_basic_dynamo/MyApp is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX:table/McCannHealth"
```

The weird thing is that I made new roll called lambda_full_access and changed it for the skill, but it's still assuming another roll. What am I doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already figured it out, but you'd have to edit the permission JSON yourself. So when your creating a new IAM role, open the "Advanced settings" and change the content of the JSON to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "cognito-identity:ListIdentityPools",
                "cognito-sync:GetCognitoEvents",
                "cognito-sync:SetCognitoEvents",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "events:*",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "kinesis:DescribeStream",
                "kinesis:ListStreams",
                "kinesis:PutRecord",
                "lambda:*",
                "logs:*",
                "s3:*",
                "sns:ListSubscriptions",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "sns:Unsubscribe",
                "sns:Publish",
                "sqs:ListQueues",
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "iot:GetTopicRule",
                "iot:ListTopicRules",
                "iot:CreateTopicRule",
                "iot:ReplaceTopicRule",
                "iot:AttachPrincipalPolicy",
                "iot:AttachThingPrincipal",
                "iot:CreateKeysAndCertificate",
                "iot:CreatePolicy",
                "iot:CreateThing",
                "iot:ListPolicies",
                "iot:ListThings",
                "iot:DescribeEndpoint"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Above gives a full access to DynamoDB. JSON for other permissions are available on AWS as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly permission issue. You have selected a role "lambda_full_access". If you have created that role then please check you have give dynamoDB GetItem permission to that role. If you have selected one of the default role then you can either you can edit that role and attach a custom policy with below policy,

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "YouID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Scan"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "YOUR DYNAMODB ARN HERE"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It means now your role will have full lambda access and dynamoDB access for only "GetItem" and "Scan". If you want more permission like "PutItem" etc. you can add it.

Alternatively you can create a custom role and can attach policies for Lambda access and can create a custom policy with the above given setting.